# Run-time error 13: Listbox with checkboxes to excel cells

Tags: excel, vba, forms, listbox

I click the button and I can fill the rows with all the values from the textboxes, but the listbox is not working, I can see the items but when I select them and click the commandbutton2 they don't transfer .
Keeps showing the Run-time Error 13 Type mismatch.

To add items to my listbox I used the RowSource in the ListBox Properties =Sheetname!G12:G24 and when I open the Form it everything there.

```
Private Function selectneg() As Integer
Dim i As Integer


For i = LBound(ListBox1.List) To UBound(ListBox1.List)
   If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then

      selectneg = selectneg & ListBox1.List(i) & " , "


   End If

Next i

If Len(selectneg) > 0 Then

   selectneg = Left(selectneg, Len(selectneg) - 1)  'here is where the error appear 

End If
```

[image: print from this code]

Comment: `selectneg() As Integer` ? Try As String

Comment: now it's solved.. Thank you @CDP1802

Comment: Note `" , "` is 3 characters so the 1 here  `selectneg = Left(selectneg, Len(selectneg) - 1)` should be 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `selectneg = selectneg & ListBox1.List(i) & " , "` you are trying to put an string in an integer.

If you need a string  use a string, you can't use a different type as string